# Access violation at adress...

Tags: delphi

Собственно говоря, вот элемент кода, ошибка при попытке выполнить сроку   ***`setlength(masofFD2, fv2);`***

```
procedure FromTo (var Count:integer; var arrofAB : array of string; var arofd : array of string; var Steps : array of integer; var fV : integer; var masofFD : array of integer);
  var
    f2,fv1,q,stt,i,ij,ii,j,jj,ste : integer;
    //// steef = f  stte = f2
    fv2,ff : integer;
    arFr1 : array of integer;
    arTo1 : array of integer;
    foto : integer;
    va1, fromE : boolean;
    ZakS, PosS : ReString;
    stepsV : array of integer;
     masofFD2 : array of integer;
     dpvr : boolean;
     dpvrsh : integer;
     ffv : integer; /// êîë-âî ëèíèé íà êàæîì øàãå.
  begin
  dpvrsh := 0;
  ffv := 0;
  dpvr := false;
  dopver := 430000;
  va1 := false;
  fromE := false;
  setlength(arFr1, count*2);
  setlength(arTo1, count*2);
  foto := 0;
  ff := fv;
  fv2 := fv;
  f2 := 0;
  ste:=0;
  f := 0;
  stt :=0;
  q:=0;
  fv1:=fv;
  setlength(masofFD2, fv);
  for i:=0 to fv1 do
  masofFD2[i]:= masofFD[i];
  setlength(arrofB, Count*2);
  setlength(ZakS, Count*2);
  setlength(PosS, Count*2);
  setlength(arFrom, Count*2);
  setlength(arTo, Count*2);
  setlength(stepsV, count*2);
    for i:=0 to length(arofd)-1 do
    begin
    ZakS := D1(arofd[i]);
    if stt = fV1 then begin
    stepsV[q] := ffv;
    ffv := 0;
     inc(q);
     fv1 := DeleteAndSort(masofFD2, arFr1, arTo1, foto, fv2);
     foto :=0;
     fv2 := fv2 + fv1;
     setlength(masofFD2, fv2);
     for ij:=0 to fv1-1 do begin
      masofFD2[ff]:= masLL[ij];
      ff := ff + 1;
     end;
     f := 0;
     stt:= 0;
    end;

    inc(stt);
      for ii:=0 to st1-1 do
      begin
      if ZakS[ii] = '~' then continue;
      for j:=0 to length(arrofAB)-1 do begin
        PosS := D(arrofAB[j]);
       for jj:=0 to st-1 do  begin
       if PosS[jj] = '~' then continue;
       if ZakS[ii] = PosS[jj] then
        if fromE = false then
        begin
          fromE := true;
          f := j+1;
          arFrom[ste] := f;
          arFr1[foto] := f;
          ffv := ffv + 1;
          if arFrom[ste-1] = arFrom[ste] then
          begin
          dpvrsh := dpvrsh  + 1;
          dpvr := true;
          dopVer:= dopVer+1;
          va1 := true;
          arFrom[ste-1] := dopVer;
          arFr1[foto-1] := dopVer; end;
        end
        else
        begin
          fromE :=false;
          f2 := j+1;
          arTo[ste] := f2;
          arTo1[foto] := f2;
          if (arTo[ste-1] = arTo[ste]) and (va1) then begin arTo1[foto] := dopVer; arTo[ste] := dopVer; va1 := false; end;
          arrofB[ste] := ZakS[ii];
          if ii>0 then
          if ZakS[ii-1] = '~' then arrofB[ste] := ZakS[ii-1]+ZakS[ii];
          ste := ste +1;
          foto := foto + 1;
          f := f+1;
          end;
          end;
        end;
       end;
    end;
    RepAndInv(arrofB);
    if (dpvr) then
    drawdopV(dpvrsh);
    drawLine(arFrom, arTo, cordinateX, cordinateY);
  end;
```

Никак не могу понять, почему возникает ошибка (возникает на конкретном шаге, т.к.
когда

```
masofFD2 = ('1','4','3','8');
```

а

```
fv2  = 9;

p.s. глобальные
    var
      dopVer : integer;
      smewpripost : integer; /// Ñìåùåíèå ïðè ïîñòðîåíèè âåðøíè
      masALLB : array of integer;
      iformasallb : integer;
      cordinateX : array of integer;
      cordinateY : array of integer;
      f,l, yV, iii : integer;
      arofLb : array of TLabel;
      arrofB : array of string; /// Ôàêòû ( òî ÷òî ïèøåì íà äóãàõ
      arFrom : array of integer;
      arTo : array of integer;
      arofLbDis : array of TLabel;
      arofIm : array of TImage;
      arofX : array of integer;
      arrofIDis : array of string;
      arofY : array of integer;
      txfF : array of string;
      txfL : array of string;
      arrd : array of string;
      masLL : repetedi; // ìàññèâ âåðøèí íà êàæäîì øàãå.
      IFB,st, st1 : integer;
      arrofDis : array of string;
```

Вот функция deleteandsort ( p.s. Спасибо за ответы )

```
function DeleteAndSort(masF : array of integer; masA : array of integer;var masB : array of integer; var ste,count : integer):integer;/// Сортирует и удаляет повторяющиеся элементы
  var
    n : integer;
    ii : integer;
    i : integer;
    j : integer;
    elem : integer;
    st : integer;
    masL : array of integer;
    masofNS : array of integer;
  begin
  setlength(masofNS, ste*2);
  setlength(masL, ste*2);
  st:=0;
  elem :=0;
    for i:=0 to count-1 do
     begin
       elem := masF[i];
       for ii:=0 to ste-1 do
        begin

      if elem = masA[ii]
      then masA[ii] := 0;
      if elem = masB[ii]
      then masB[ii] := 0;
    end;
 end;
 for i:=0 to ste-1 do
  begin
    if masA[i] <> 0 then
      begin
        masL[st]:= masA[i];
        st := st + 1;

      end;
     if masB[i] <> 0 then
      begin
        masL[st]:= masB[i];
        st := st + 1;
      end;
  end;
  masLL := DeleteRepeted(masL,st);
  n := length(masLL);
  masLL := DeleteRepeted(masLL, n);
  // Можно вписать фукцию для отрисовки вершин
  drawaLLV(masLL);
  //
  result := length(masLL);
```

end;

Comment: объявление массива, текст ошибки  и типы переменных в студию!

Comment: var
    f2,fv1,q,stt,i,ij,ii,j,jj,ste : integer;
    //// steef = f  stte = f2
    fv2,ff : integer;
    arFr1 : array of integer;
    arTo1 : array of integer;
    foto : integer;
    va1, fromE : boolean;
    ZakS, PosS : ReString;
    stepsV : array of integer;
     masofFD2 : array of integer;
     dpvr : boolean;
     dpvrsh : integer;
     ffv : integer; /// êîë-âî ëèíèé íà êàæîì øàãå.

Comment: Да-да, хорошо бы всю процедуру целиком.

Comment: поправил ( теперь вся процедура) п.с. есть еще глобальные переменные

Comment: прошу прощения за не читабельность кода. если поможет то проблема стала возникать когда начал делать setlength(..., count*2); раньше было просто count но к сожалению в некоторых случаях вызывала ошибку ( ну понятно какую ).

Comment: HELP HELP... нашел еще такую странную вещь, иду по шагам в отладке все работает. если запускаю в автоматическом режиме ( или как там оно называется ) то вылетает ошибка. В чем мб дело ?

Comment: по симптомам похоже, что вы где-то раньше в память своего массива залезаете и портите указатель

Comment: покажите, что делает функция DeleteAndSort. Может быть в ней указатель портится?

Comment: Не понимаю зачем передавать masB через var, и, вот, сцуко, явно у Вас перебор с глобальными переменными, явно где то тупо портится оно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

пишу на тот случай если автор вопроса все еще не нашел ответа на свой вопрос... и не отчаялся его искать...:)
во первых... 
возможно опечатка автора вопроса...

> masofFD2 : array of **integer**;
>
> Никак не могу понять, почему возникает
> ошибка (возникает на конкретном шаге,
> т.к. когда masofFD2 =
> **('1','4','3','8')**;

во вторых... 
**попытаюсь описать последовательность** "интересных" строк кода, из-за которой **setlength(masofFD2, fv2)** ругается.

в функции DeleteAndSort используешь переменную **ste**, она же при вызове является переменной **foto**, которая

```
foto := 0;
```

вернувшись к функции DeleteAndSort, обратим внимание на участок кода:

```
for ii:=0 to ste-1 do begin
    if elem = masA[ii] then 
        masA[ii] := 0;
    if elem = masB[ii] then 
        masB[ii] := 0;
end;
```

т.е. здесь **ii:= 0 to -1**,... и куда запишем значение 0? masA[-1]?masB[-1]?

**та же проблема в следующем цикле** for, который формирует **masL**,
далее она используется (кстати setlength(masL, **ste** *2) и для чего в функции **masofNS**):

```
masLL := DeleteRepeted(masL,st);
```

где **masLL** глобальная переменная типа **repetedi** (repetedi??) 
и результат функции

```
result := length(masLL)
```

который влияет на устанавливаемую длину **masofFD2**

```
fv1 := DeleteAndSort(masofFD2, arFr1, arTo1, foto, fv2)
fv2 := fv2 + fv1;
setlength(masofFD2, fv2);
```

p.s. **не увидел ни одного try_except`а**

p.p.s. желательно вначале тела функции дать ей значение по умолчанию (result:=0)*

p.p.p.s. много переменных

Answer (score 1):

Если ошибочка в цикле вылетает,

```
  fv1:=fv;
  setlength(masofFD2, fv);
  for i:=0 to fv1 do
    masofFD2[i]:= masofFD[i];
```

то я бы решил что дело в том что переменная `fv <> Length(masofFD)`

Попробуйте включить проверку на границы и отлавливайте RangeException? И как то очень сложно у Вас - я бы архитектуру бы поменял бы. И подразбил бы на методы. И сократил бы количество переменных раз в десять минимум.

Да, ещё можете в дебагере по адресу по которому аксесс виолайшен лезет посмотреть в каком массиве это происходит.

**P.S.**

А не ту строчку посмотрел :-)

Если именно падает на установке длинны массива - то проверьте значение у переменной **fv2**  - может отрицательное вдруг?

Comment: ошибка обращения к памяти. у него проблема не в длине массива, а в битом указателе на массив

Comment: ну тогда DeleteAndSort функцию в студию

Comment: я уже попросил написать ее. ждем фитбэк

Comment: @teanЫЧ а fitback как переводится -- "подходит в зад" или как-то иначе?

Comment: @alexlz, "фидбэк", он же "feedback" (на слух "фитбэк") - это обратная связь. Гуглтранслейт какбэ [намекает][1]

[1]: http://translate.google.ru/#en/ru/feedback

Comment: @teanЫЧ Спасибо за сурдоперевод. Кажись понял...

Comment: Спасибо за ответы, добавил функцию Deleteandsort в топик

Answer (score -3):

**setlength** если с 2умя значениями, то он первую переменную требует в формате **string**
если с 3емя значениями (с целью установить длину массива) то нужно указывать 3 значения)

Comment: спасибо за ответ.
 но прошу прощения за возможною глупость, нашел (не знаю можно ли давать ссылку на wiki ) http://articles.org.ru/delphispr/SetLength.php там пишут про то что вы говорили, но я никак не могу понять как мне сделать, т.к. там речь ведется про многомерный массив а у меня одномерный.

Comment: > setlength если с 2умя значениями, то он первую переменную требует в формате string если с 3емя значениями (с целью установить длину массива) то нужно указывать 3 значения)

@Manitikyl, это кто вам такое сказал? И что это за третий параметр помимо, собственно, массива и его новой длины (Мы ведь об одномерных массивах тут говорим?).

Comment: количество параметров ф-ции setlength соответствует 1(массив) + размерность массива.
то есть для 1-мерного массива - 2 параметра, для двумерного - 3, для 3-мерного - 4 и т. д.

Comment: это конечно все хорошо ) но в чем у меня ошибка то? явно массив у меня одномерный.